# Easier way to switch between AP mode and WIFI client

Tags: networking, wifi

**Switch to wifi mode:**

1. mask this three lines in dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

2. `restart dhcpcd service`
3. `stop dnsmasq service`
4. `stop hostpad service`

**Switch to AP mode:**

1. mask out this three lines in dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

2. `start dnsmasq service`
3. `start hostpad service`
4. `restart dhcpcd.service`

Is there a way not mask/ mask out the last few lines in dhcpcd.conf to switch between AP and wifi mode? It will simplify my program.

Comment: The modes in WiFi is AP (Access Point) and STA (station)

Comment: Oh by the way, perhaps dual mode could be your solution! Modern WiFi hardware can be AP and STA at the same time, so no need to switch !

Comment: i didn't know it can be dual mode. For now im just copying ap file to dhcpcd.conf according to the condition.